# Possibly very stupid Kotlin constructor idea

Tags: kotlin

I realize this is probably impossible, I've gone down a rabbit hole trying to construct a tree recursively from the root node which has lead me to this mess...

I've removed all the fluff to just show the root of the "problem" (where the problem is more than likely me trying to do something that just makes no CS sense at all).

So, I have a class like this:

```
class Node(parent: Node?, child: Node?)
```

And I want to instantiate it like this (passing "this" - which hasn't been instantiated yet as the parent param to the child node of the root. Just writing this now I realize it seems super stupid... but is this possible in any way in Kotlin?

```
fun exampleFail() {
    val root = Node(null, Node(root, null)) // Not possible because of compiler
}
```

EDIT: To clarify - I'm fully aware that "this" here would refer to the class that exampleFail belongs to. When I wrote "this" I meant "the node under construction..." and yes, I'm fully aware this is syntactically incorrect but I'm trying to figure out if there is any way to accomplish this.

EDIT 2: Replaced "this" with "root" to make clearer what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: Since you want to create a tree, why the second param is a Node referring to a single child? Shouldn't it be a MutableList<Node>?

Comment: Simplest reproducible example. Yes I'm working on a tree structure, the code is a lot more in depth than I posted here, but the "problem" really has nothing to do with the tree, it's that I want to pass the under construction object to the constructor of the child (I don't know if there is a name for this, but I guess it's like recursive constructor?). Also don't even know if it's possible.

Comment: I.e. I'm trying to pass "root" to the child Node constructor in the same expression as root is constructed. So root is undefined at this point.

Comment: DISCLAIMER: I don't know kotlin. Why not make it `Node(parent: Node? = null, child: Node? = null)`, then give Node a variadic (or MutableList like mTak suggests) `addChildren` method that automatically binds the parent/child relationships and use it like so: val root = `Node().addChildren(Node().addChildren(Node()), Node(), Node())`

Answer (score 4):

Technically I don't know what you need it for, but if you are able to modify `Node` class, then you can add a workaround of sorts like this

```
class Node(parent: Node?, child: Node?, shouldCreateChild: Boolean = false) {
    val child: Node?

    init {
        this.child = child ?: when {
            shouldCreateChild -> Node(this, null)
            else -> null
        }
    }
}
```

So inside the constructor, you "see" the object that is under construction. You could even pass in a lambda of `initializer: Node.() -> Unit` and wreak havoc.